# Calculate vector

Tags: matrices, vectors, vector-analysis

okay so this is my question, calculate a vector that points in the same direction as $x=\begin{bmatrix} 31 \\ 1 \\ 11 \end{bmatrix}$ of length 3. The answer is supposed to be written as $w=(x,y,z)^T = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$.

So this is what I thought -
Unit vector times 3 - $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{93}{\sqrt{1083}} \\ \frac{3}{\sqrt{1083}} \\ \frac{33}{\sqrt{1083}} \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please read the [formatting tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and edit your question to make the mathematics readable.

Comment: Re: your question about the notation $(\;,\;,\;)^T$, yes it does stand for transpose. It's just a way of writing column vectors inline without screwing up line spacing too much.

Comment: Hi sorry it doesn’t let me edit the question and thank you Ell, I thought it was that, so am I correct with what I did please?

Comment: @Emmanuelle You've done it correctly by calculating the unit vector in the same direction then multiplying by $3$.

Comment: You are absolutely right!

Comment: Thank you CyclotomicField, P.J., YU and Tristan Duquesne for editing it!